# CallableStatement PostgreSQL :Invalid number of parameters error

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, stored-functions, callable-statement

Im trying to write sample stored functions in postgresql and call them using the CallableStatement offered by JDBC.

Here's some my test code

```
Consumer bean =new Consumer();
CallableStatement pstmt = null;
try {
con.setAutoCommit(false);
String  query = "{ ? = call getData( ? ) }";
pstmt = con.prepareCall(query); 
 pstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);
      pstmt.setInt(2,5);
      pstmt.execute(); // execute update statement
      bean=(Consumer)pstmt.getObject(1);
       System.out.println("bean"+bean.getConsumer_name());
```

And my Stored function is of the form .

```
CREATE FUNCTION getData(int) RETURNS SETOF db_consumer AS $$
 SELECT * FROM db_consumer WHERE consumer_id = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

However, I'm getting the following error when I try to run the code .

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A CallableStatement was executed with an invalid    number of  parameters .
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need a CallableStatement as you should be able to run `select * from getData(5)` directly:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from getData(?)")
pstmt.setInt(1,5);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.execute(); 
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply,I've done that with preparedstatement before . Was just wondering how to use CallableStatement..

Comment: I don't think this is possible. With a CallableStatement you would need an OUT parameter (e.g. a REF CURSOR) in order to process the result. But the way you create your function it does not define a refcursor. I think using a SELECT is the only option you have.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call a SETOFF function via a Callable Statement. That's not going to happen! You'll always get an error.

PostgreSQL's stored functions can return results in two different ways. The function may return either a refcursor value or a SETOF some datatype. Depending on which of these return methods are used determines how the function should be called. 

 Functions that return data as a set should not be called via the CallableStatement interface, but instead should use the normal Statement or PreparedStatement interfaces.